# Handlebars.js Not Working

Tags: handlebars.js

Good morning,

I have recently begun working with handlebars.js and I cannot figure out why the code is not working. I am not getting any console errors so is this a runtime issue? I have attached a codepen project for review. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/brandonewell/pen/mPmdJa)

```
var source = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = {events: [
  {
"image": "src='images/logo.png' alt='Leon Bridges'",
"artist": "Leon Bridges",
"venue": "White Water Tavern",
"time": "8:00PM",
"type": "music"
  },
  {
"image": "src='images/logo.png' alt='Coheed & Cambria'",
"artist": "Coheed &amp; Cambria",
"venue": "Revolution Music Room",
"time": "9:00PM",
"type": "music"
  }
]};

$("body").html(template(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working CodePen: http://codepen.io/christophethiry/pen/yObVaW

Simply add the below code around your script to make sure handlebar has loaded before it executes:

```
$(document).ready( function() { // Your code here });
```

I also changed the URL of Handlebar library to make sure to have the resource correct version.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
```